# API Voiding a delay_capture=true Charge

Tags: square-connect

I did a Charge with delay_capture=true. The response has card status as "AUTHORIZED" as expected.

I then Voided the transaction. I posted to

```
https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/[location id]/transactions/[transaction id]/void
```

with the headers

```
Authorization: Bearer [live access token]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type:application/json
```

and received the reply

```
{}
```

as expected.

If I do a Retrieve Transaction on the one I voided through the API, it does show status as "VOIDED"

In the dashboard it doesn't show any Voids, nor does it show the Transaction. Is that to be expected?

However, on my credit card statement, the amount still shows as "Pending."
Does voiding a transaction not get sent to the credit card company so the Pending charge is removed?

My concern is it showing on the credit card statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct the voided transaction will not show in the Transaction section of the online Dashboard.

It will show in the [Transaction Status](https://squareup.com/dashboard/sales/reports/transaction-status) report on your Square Dashboard. The Transactions Status shows information about uncompleted transactions. This includes canceled, declined, expired Offline Mode, and uncompleted transactions in which a customer’s card was swiped (or manually entered) but not successfully charged.

Additionally this void charge should disappear from your statement within a few business days.